# How to determine which element was moved in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to find the difference between two arrays, by finding out which element was moved.  I know that one element exactly will be moved and that the order will be maintained for the rest of the list, but am unable to figure out how to find this.

Example:

> A: 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> B: 2 3 4 5 1 6

All of the elements exist in both lists, but how do I find out that the element 1 moved from index 0 to index 4?

My basic approach that I took but is not working is:

```
//Original array
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

//New array
var b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6];

for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] != b[i] && a[i+1] != b[i]) {
        console.log(b[i] + " moved");
    }
}
```

I have fixed by code to print out b[i] instead of a[i], but it is not working in all cases such as:

> A: 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> B: 1, 4, 2, 3

Comment: define "not working". How does it fail? It looks good to me.

Comment: @JanDvorak That code tells me that 5 moved, when the answer should be 1.

Comment: @Smash ... what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Flipper sounds like you should be printing `b[i]`, then

Comment: @JanDvorak Ah you are right!  I just figured it out and was coming back to this page to answer my own question, but I can accept your answer if you write one?

Comment: @Flipper This looks like a typo question to me. No need to keep it around.

Comment: @JanDvorak Ok I thought it could be helpful as I searched a long while for a similar question, but was unable to find it and was stumped.  Should I delete it?

Comment: @Flipper do you think it could be helpful? If you do, you can keep it around. Michael has already posted an answer (actually, it looks like a better approach than yours)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the second condition in your `if` statement. In your example, when element `a[0]` has moved, `a[0+1] === b[0]`, so the `if` clause evaluates to false.

Try instead,

```
var idx = 0;
var len = a.length;
while ((a[idx] === b[idx] || a[idx] === b[idx+1]) && idx < len) {
    idx++;
}
console.log('Element a[' + idx + ']=' + a[idx] + ' moved.');
```

Comment: I find that it breaks on something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/76kTy/  As it should be that the element 4 has moved.

Comment: @Flipper why not post the example here?

Comment: @Flipper consider `[1,2,3,4] / [1,2,4,3]`. What value should be printed? Also, your code doesn't work for elements moved backwards either.

Comment: @JanDvorak I see the problem there in determining which one was moved.  In my case I am comfortable with either one of those values (3 or 4).

Comment: I've updated my answer. It seems to work, in an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/76kTy/2/. Do you still find a case that it doesn't satisfy?

Comment: @Michael I just copied your answer over to my code and am unable to find a case where it breaks.  Thanks!

Comment: This might be a silly concern, but this code will break on `b[idx+1]` if no items have actually been moved. For instance, I'm currently using it in conjunction with [angular-ui/ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable), which fires events even when an item has been lifted up and put back in the same place.

Answer (score 4):

basically, if I understand correctly, an element moving means it is deleted and inserted
somewhere else.
so you first find the first point where there was a deletion/insertion:

```
function whichMoved(a, b) {
      for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) {
```

now, if it was a deletion, then the element has been moved forward, meaning, inserted in a greater index in b, and all elements between the indices are shifted to the left,
meaning the the next element has moved one place to backward:

```
if(a[i+1] == b[i]) {
    console.log(a[i] + " moved forward");
    break;
}
```

otherwise, the element was moved backward:

```
else {
    console.log(b[i] + " moved backward")
    break;
}
```

the whole thing:

```
//Original array
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

//testing
whichMoved(a, [2,3,4,5,1,6]); //prints 1 moved forward
whichMoved(a, [5,1,2,3,4,6]); //prints 5 moved backward
function whichMoved(a, b) {
  for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) {
      if(a[i+1] == b[i]) {
        console.log(a[i] + " moved forward");
        break;
      } else {
        console.log(b[i] + " moved backward")
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very good so I have upvoted it, but Michael's answer is very concise which is what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `.inArray()` it will return the index, starting at 0 and returns -1 if not found:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

//New array
var b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6];

for(i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var j = $.inArray(a[i], b);

    if(i != j){
        console.log(a[i], "moved to index "+j);
    }else{
        console.log(a[i], "not moved");
    } 
}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rdzj4/

Comment: That will print out all of the elements.  And I don't see how inArray will help me since all of the elements exist in both arrays.

Comment: Sorry I haven't not understood well at first. Yes you can use inArray since it returns the index you can compare it with `i`. See my updated answer. Thanks

Comment: I also same problem and in all answer here I see this very simple and very easy understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Edited- probably not needed, but I hate to leave a wrong answer.

Here I look at the distance each item is from its original index,

and figure the one that is most out of order is the mover-

This assumes in [2,1,3,4,5,6] it is the two that moved, not the 1,

and in [1,2, 3, 4, 6, 5] it is the 6, not the 5.

```
function whoMoved(a, b){
    var max= 0, min= a.length, dist, 
    order= b.map(function(itm, i){
        dist= i-a.indexOf(itm);
        if(dist<min) min= dist;
        if(dist>max) max= dist;
        return dist;
    });
    if(Math.abs(min)>= max) max= min;
    return b[order.indexOf(max)];
}
```

//test

```
var a= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var b= [1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5];//6 to left
var c= [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6];//2 to to right
var d= [3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6];//3 to left
var e= [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6];//1 to right

[whoMoved(a, b), whoMoved(a, c), whoMoved(a, d),whoMoved(a, e)];

/*  returned value: (Array) [6,2,3,1] */
```

Comment: this works when you move an element to the right, but not to the left